# custom login redirect on login route after loggedIn - laravel

Tags: php, redirect, laravel-5, authentication

I am Creating Student Portal For My university.

There are multiply users in This portal e.g student , teacher , staff , & administration.

I have Successfully Created Custom login redirect based on Multiply Users
e.g
when Student login he redirected on localhost:8000/student/dash-board similarly teacher redirected on localhost:8000/teacher/dash-board
..
..

LoginController.php  (Works Perfectly After login)

```
   public function redirectTo()
{
    $userRollId = Auth::user()->user_role_id;

    if( $userRollId == 1)
    {
           return route('administrationDashboard');
    }
    elseif ($userRollId == 2) {

            return route('teacherDashboard');
    }
    elseif ($userRollId == 3) {
            return route('studentDashboard');
    }
    elseif ($userRollId == 4) {
            return route('departmentalStaffDashboard');
    }
     elseif ($userRollId == 4) {
            return 'departmentalStaff/dashboard';       
    }
}
```

But I am facing problem while I am testing my Application.

Senior is that
I logged in as Student and after login redirect on 
http://localhost:8000/student/dash-board

For test when I hit  localhost:8000/login
Its redirect to localhost:8000/home
It should redirect on localhost:8000/student/dash-board but not :(

I think LoginController logic is not apply on this after login.
Maybe LoginController logic Only Apply when we try to login.

So there is any solution or Suggestion ??

Comment: do you use laravel `Auth` middle-ware ?

Comment: check your auth controller there is a protected variable $redirecTo you have to change it

Comment: Are you using `guest` middleware in your login route?

Comment: please check if the redirectTo() function is called using echo $userRollId;die();

Comment: please shows us the login function in your controller

Comment: @hassan Yes I am using Laravel Auth Middle-ware

Comment: @Rodrane yeh I edited this variable through redirectTo() function according to user. its working perfect but hit localhost:8000/login its redirect to /home becuause $redirecTo = 'home' 
and redirectTo() function is not applied on it.

Comment: @PankitGami I created separate middle ware for every user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are using `LoginController` of laravel. In `LoginController`, it attach the `guest` middleware to all the route except `logout` ([Check Here](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php#L37)).

So you have to add the code to `\App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated` class.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        $userRollId = Auth::user()->user_role_id;

        if( $userRollId == 1)
        {
            return route('administrationDashboard');
        }
        elseif ($userRollId == 2) {

            return route('teacherDashboard');
        }
        elseif ($userRollId == 3) {
            return route('studentDashboard');
        }
        elseif ($userRollId == 4) {
            return route('departmentalStaffDashboard');
        }
        elseif ($userRollId == 4) {
            return 'departmentalStaff/dashboard';
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Better thing is to create a static function :

```
Class Helper {
    public static function redirectByRole($userRollId) {
        if( $userRollId == 1)
            {
                return route('administrationDashboard');
            }
            elseif ($userRollId == 2) {

                return route('teacherDashboard');
            }
            elseif ($userRollId == 3) {
                return route('studentDashboard');
            }
            elseif ($userRollId == 4) {
                return route('departmentalStaffDashboard');
            }
            elseif ($userRollId == 4) {
                return 'departmentalStaff/dashboard';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And call it like this :

**From your controller :**

```
public function redirectTo()
{
    $userRollId = Auth::user()->user_role_id;

    return Helper::redirectByRole($userRollId);
}
```

**From `RedirectIfAuthenticated` middleware :**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        $userRollId = Auth::user()->user_role_id;

        return Helper::redirectByRole($userRollId);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: Thanks its works for me :) I just modify your code little bit and its works perfect as i want :) 

RedirectIfAuthenticated.php

if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            
             $userRollId = Auth::user()->user_role_id;

              if( $userRollId == 1)
                    {
                        return redirect()->route('administrationDashboard');
                    }
...
...  
}

        return $next($request);
    }